# How to install tmux on Centos?

Tags: centos, software-installation, package-management, yum, tmux

When I execute `yum install tmux`, it gives me an error:

```
Setting up Install Process 
No package tmux available. 
Error: Nothing to do
```

Any idea on how to solve this issue?

Comment: For the most current releases of tmux for CentOS and RHEL: https://anni.galaxy4.net/?page_id=39

Answer (score 9):

By installing the correct repository, and installing it from that repo:

```
# yum install epel-release
# yum install tmux
```